# Create shared container for multiple server instances in c# application

Tags: c#, caching, data-structures, containers, shared-memory

Our .NET web application has 4 server instances (scaled), which are working together with load balancing mechanism (1/4 of requests to each instance). I need to store shared data across server using application level data structures. I tried to create static singleton dictionary object in main, but each instance of server creates It's own dictionary object and data is not shared.

So the question is - Is there any way to have shared container in application layer for all the instances or the only way is using cache(ex. redis cache) or db ?

Comment: You're talking about creating your own distributed cache/DB. Just use an existing one. Or investigate sticky sessions if that's an option.

Comment: Dude you have to use an external cache that all instances can use. It is not possible for several instances of a same program to use another instance's objects even it is a singleton resource. All of this instances have their own objects. Just look for key/value storages like Redis, Memcached, etc

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about sticky sessions.